# URL rewrite for sub-folder, sub-folder need beautiful SEO friendly URL

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am working with custom website. My current folder structure like:

```
Main Dir (httpdocs)/Stores (sub-folder) / eol (sub-folder and site files)

Full Path /httpdocs/stores/eol
```

and I have three pages Like

```
categories.php (categories?category_id=352)
allproducts.php (allproducts?cat_id=624)
products.php (products?productid=1118&cat_id=296)
```

My Current .htaccess is

```
 RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /stores/eol/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L] # Removing .php extention 

    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /stores/eol/categories?category_id=$1 [QSA,NC,L] 
    RewriteRule ^cat-([^/]*)\.html$ /stores/eol/allproducts?cat_id=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /stores/eol/products?productid=$1&cat_id=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Now want to show page with beautiful or SEO friendly URL.

Your help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're aiming for:
`352.html` -> `categories.php?category_id=352`
`cat-624.html` -> `allproducts.php?cat_id=624`
`1118/296.html` -> `products.php?productid=1118&cat_id=29`

I believe you're looking for something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /stores/eol/
RewriteRule ^(\d+)\.html$ categories.php?category_id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^cat-(\d+)\.html$ allproducts.php?cat_id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(\d+)/(\d+)\.html$ products.php?productid=$1&cat_id=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Not Work! Thanks for your time

Comment: Try it without RewriteBase and using `/stores/eol/` in the rewritten URL instead.